# Git code to extract commit comparisons between each commit of the source code file in a report file (Excel or PDF) in a given year

Tags: git, report, diff

I am wondering if there is a git command which would take two inputs (year and source code file) and extract code differences (only insertions and deletions) between each/all commits of the specified source code file in a single report file (e.g. PDF or Excel).

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to obtain can be split in two phases, commit detection and output formatting.

**For the commit detection part**, it's quite trivial within git, you could have an alias along the lines of

```
# yfh for "Yearly File History"
git config --global alias.yfh '!f() { git log -p --pretty=format:"" --no-merges --since=$1 --until=$(($1+1)) -- $2; }; f'

# which would be used like this, for year 2017 :

git yfh 2017 path/to/your/file
```

However, you'd still have to figure out the exact way you want to format it for your expected end result. ("Excel" here is quite vague, and PDF writing will mostly depend on your system/software)